# Как думаете место быть названием переменных и тд на русском языке?

Tags: c#, синтаксис

Кто в англ очень слаб, и не знает даже базовых слов, они же не просто так ввели возможность писать на русском языке.
Понятное дело свой проект писать и с ним работать только вам, никому больше с ним дела иметь не придётся , хотя для портфолио на собеседовании была б интересна реакцияА другое дело в команде. Вообщем что думаете, место быть или не быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если совсем всё плохо, пишите транслитом, кириллицу использовать очень не советую.

А так, есть онлайн-переводчики, заодно и язык подучите. C# весь состоит из английских слов, значит хоть как-то воспринимаете английский текст.

Если бы мне кандидат на вакансию прислал тестовое задание с кириллицей в названиях членов класса или переменных, я бы его даже читать не стал. Помимо странного выбора кириллицы это означает, что разработчик совсем не знает английский, а это признак серьёзных проблем в дальнейшем изучении возможностей .NET. Так как зачастую документация либо криво переведена на русский, либо вообще не переведена.

Comment: А вы уже такое встречали? Я на днях форум читал, человек впервые за 10 лет увидел код, в котором, имена переменным даны на русском. Я говорит 10 лет на шарпе пишу, много что видел, но чтоб такогоо

Comment: @gachi_muchenik здесь встречал

Comment: @gachi_muchenik Следует отметить, что это лишь частное мнение aepot, которое ничем не подтверждается. У меня на работе в одном проекте есть классы с названиями свойств на русском языке (написаны до меня). Особой пользы от этого нет, но это абсолютно поддерживаемый сценарий, и это лишь вопрос выбора стиля кода в конкретном проекте.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight всё верно, но ваш случай скорее исключение, и новичку объективно не стоит на него ориентироваться.